# Selecting different data with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to select various bits of data out of my insert.php page. Such as post id, username and users id so far.. And I will be adding other bits of selected data. Now I could get the id of the div with response, but when I added more queries and echo them out they ended up all together so I had my postidusernameuserid all in one string. How do I separate them?

Also I'm aware of the depreciated MYSQL_ I just haven't got around to updating my code yet.

AJAX

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var content = $("#toid").val();
            var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insert.php",
                data: {toid:content, newmsg: newmsg},
                success: function(response){
                    $("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='divider-"+response+"'><div class='userinfo'>"+newmsg+"<a href='/profile.php?username="+response+"'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('"+response+"');\">X</div></div></div>");
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

INSERT.PHP

```
$check = "SELECT streamitem_id FROM streamdata";
        $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
        $resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
    echo $resultArr['streamitem_id'];

$check = "SELECT username,id FROM users";
        $check1     =    mysql_query($check);
        $resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
    echo $resultArr['username'];
    echo $resultArr['id'];
```

Is it a case of  success: function(response,responsetwo){ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP try returning the data in JSON format.

```
echo json_encode(array);
```

The response variable in JavaScript will be an object you can get the data from.

```
console.log(response['username']);
```

---

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var content = $("#toid").val();
        var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { toid: content, newmsg: newmsg },
            success: function(response){
                $("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='divider-"+response['streamitem_id']+"'><div class='userinfo'>"+newmsg+"<a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'><img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped"+response['id']+".jpg\" onerror='this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:0px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('"+response['id']+"');\">X</div></div></div>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$json = array();
$check = "SELECT `streamitem_id` FROM `streamdata`";
$check1 = mysql_query($check);
$resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
$json['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id'];
mysql_free_result($check1);

$check = "SELECT `username`, `id` FROM `users`";
$check1 = mysql_query($check);
$resultArr = mysql_fetch_array($check1);
$json['username'] = $resultArr['username'];
$json['id'] = $resultArr['id'];
mysql_free_result($check1);

echo json_encode($json);
```

I took the liberty of guessing where you wanted to use 'username', 'id', and 'streamitem_id'.

Comment: In your PHP file, create an array and add to it the data you want to return, i.e. $json['streamitem_id'] = $resultArr['streamitem_id']. Once all the data you want returned is in $json, echo json_encode($json).

Comment: It was more the console log I was talking about. But that is useful also.

Comment: In JavaScript, the response variable will be an object (assuming jQuery is able to determine that the response is in JSON.)  You can even do typeof(response) if you want to make sure.  See how to access the different values in the response object:

$("#homestatusid").prepend("<div id='divider-"+response['id']+"'><div class='userinfo'>"+newmsg+"<a href='/profile.php?username="+response['username']+"'>

Comment: Still went over my head. Is there anywhere I could read up to get a clearer insight please Micah. Its probably easy, just I don't seem to understand it. But I'll continue to upvote for your time and patience.

Comment: Thank you so much Comment again and I'll upvote as I can't upvote your edit.